# I am having problem witth "zindex: -1" attribute in react

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, expo

So I have created a form and it is on the same place as the buttons. I want the form to appear when the button is clicked and disappear when the cross button is clicked. The problem i am getting is that zindex -1 is not working for me and the form is overlapping the buttons so whenever i try to click one of the buttons the form is clicked (even though it is not visible).
I have done some research and apparently the zindex has been modified in react v17 and above I have also tried using elevation but that is not working either.

**Dependiecies:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions,TextInput, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import Svg, { Image, Ellipse, ClipPath } from 'react-native-svg';
import  Animated, {useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, interpolate, withTiming, withDelay, 
color}  from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

**Form code:**

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.inputformcontainer, formAnimatedStyle ]}>
    <TextInput placeholder="Email"
     placeholderTextColor="#9b1306"
      style={styles.textinput}/>
    <TextInput placeholder="Full Name"
     placeholderTextColor="#9b1306"
      style={styles.textinput}/>
    <TextInput placeholder="Password"
     placeholderTextColor="#9b1306"
      style={styles.textinput}/>
    <View style = {styles.formButton}>
      <Text style={styles.buttontext}> LOG IN </Text>
    </View>
  </Animated.View>
```

**Functions used**

```
const formAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
return{
  opacity : imagePosition.value === 0 ? withDelay(400,withTiming(1,{duration:800})) :   withTiming(0,{duration: 300})
}
```

})

CSS:

```
 inputformcontainer:{
    backgroundColor:'grey',
    color: '#000',
    marginBottom: 70,
    justifyContent : "center",
    zindex: -1,
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
    
}
```

Comment: It seems that you have a typo in your CSS code. The property `zindex` should be `zIndex` with a capital "I". Therefore, changing `zindex: -1` to `zIndex: -1` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To use `z-index` in CSS, you need declare `position` of the element. the easiest way is to add `position: relative` in your CSS(unless there is another `position` property in `StyleSheet.absoluteFill`).

And, I don't know what CSS you use, but I see `zindex` is not in camel case. so maybe your problem comes from typo. use `zIndex` instead.

Try this:

```
 inputformcontainer:{
    backgroundColor:'grey',
    color: '#000',
    marginBottom: 70,
    justifyContent : "center",
    position: relative;
    zIndex: -1,
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
}
```